# Duplicate tags getting created in git (github) repo with -e appended

Tags: git, github, git-tag

I have a github based git repo that I occasionally tag commits on.

Recently, I'm seeing tags getting duplicated with -e appended. I do tag with a pattern that has deploy in it and the date

for example today would be

`something-deploy-v20171004`

I seem to be occasionally ending up with 
`something-deploy-v20171004-e`

would then result in
`something-deploy-v20171004` AND `something-deploy-v20171004-e`

and I can't for the life of me figure out where that extra tag with -e is coming from. I generally just tag with the command line and push to the remote

```
git tag something-deploy-v20171004
git push --tags
```

Curious if anyone has seen this behavior before.

Comment: What tools are you using? Any CI or code review tools that might add their own tags?

Comment: I just use the command line mostly. We have a jenkins job that builds the code by checking out a tag and that job has a few plugins that certainly read the tags and I know some people use things like sourcetree...but the tags are generally only applied via the command line.

it's not really consistently happening though. so there must be some tool that's doing it though. none of the above things appear to be causing it